# Changing color of a child row of a listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have been trying to change the colour of my rows in a listview depending on a condition being met from my parsed string of my database. I cannot get my head around how to achieve this.

I know there seems to be examples about how to do this but I am really at a loss.

I have tried this:

```
Calms info = new Calms(this);

info.open();
String data = info.getFlareData();
info.close();

String arr[] = data.split("..\n\n");
System.out.println(arr);

ListView listView = getListView();

System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"+listView.getChildCount()+"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr));

//System.out.println("****************"+getListView().getChildCount()+"**************");


for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    System.out.println("arr["+i+"] = " + arr[i].trim());

    if(arr[i].contains("High Severity"))
    {
        // String highArr = arr[i];
        listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if(arr[i].contains("Low Severity"))
    {
        listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(arr[i].contains("Medium Severity"))
    {
        listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 136, 0));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own `Adapter` for your `ListView`. In your Adapter you can set the background color for every item without problem.

There are several tutorials for writing a custom adapter on the web:

- http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                TextView tv =  (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                String str = tv.getText().toString();

                if(str.contains("High Severity"))
                {
                    // String highArr = arr[i];
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(str.contains("Low Severity"))
                {
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else if(str.contains("Medium Severity"))
                {
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 136, 0));
                }
                return tv;
            }
        };

        setListAdapter(ad);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need extends ArrayAdapter. In method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

You can change color of row. Some example:

```
public class OneRecordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList&lt;String&gt; arhmAllForList;
    private Context context;
public OneRecordCursorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList&lt;String&gt; hm) {
        super(context, R.layout.raw_checking_knowledge, hm);
        arhmAllForList = hm;
        this.context = context;
    }
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row, parent, false);
        ...
        if ( /*some condition*/ ) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        ...
        return rowView;
    }
}
```